# How can I draw a train with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a train with Tikz like the picture[image: A simple train]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235535/134144 might be related.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In order for people to be able to help you, please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you've tried so far and what part of the code you are struggling with. As it is now, your question falls into the "do it for me" category of questions and it is unlikely you'll get answers.

Comment: @downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 7):

Here is something you can achieve with basic TikZ.
The function declared are explicit Bézier curves since I needed to know one coordinate to have a closed cycle for the windshield:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {%
            windshieldupx(\x)   = {6*(1 - \x)*\x*\x + 3*\x*\x*\x};
            windshieldupy(\x)   = {3*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x)*\x + 6*(1 - \x)*\x*\x + 2*\x*\x*\x};
            windshielddownx(\x) = {3*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x) + 9*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x)*\x + 3*(1 - \x)*\x*\x + windshieldupx(0.11)*\x*\x*\x};
            windshielddowny(\x) = {2*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x) + 3*0.4*(1 - \x)*(1 - \x)*\x + 3*0.4*(1 - \x)*\x*\x + windshieldupy(0.11)*\x*\x*\x};
        }
    ]
    
        \definecolor{window}{RGB}{5,173,190}
        \definecolor{trainbody}{RGB}{64,75,125}
        \definecolor{aroundwindow}{RGB}{50,59,97}
        \definecolor{bottomtrain}{RGB}{27,158,249}
        \definecolor{trainline}{RGB}{164,214,249}
        
        \tikzset{%
            trainwindow/.style = {%
                rectangle,
                fill           = window,
                draw           = none,
                minimum width  = 1cm,
                minimum height = 0.5cm
            }
        }
            
        \newcommand{\trainlength}{25.5}
                    
        \fill[
            trainbody
        ] plot[domain = 0:1, samples = 100] ({windshieldupx(\x)},{windshieldupy(\x)}) {%
            [rounded corners = 0.5cm]
                -- (\trainlength, 2)
        }
            -- ++(0, -2) -- cycle;
            
        \fill[%
            fill = window
        ] plot[domain = 0.11:1, samples = 100] ({windshieldupx(\x)},{windshieldupy(\x)})
            plot[domain = 0:1, samples = 100] ({windshielddownx(\x)},{windshielddowny(\x)})
            -- ({windshieldupx(0.11)},{windshieldupy(0.11)})
            -- cycle;
    
        \fill[%
            aroundwindow
        ] (3.5, {windshieldupy(0.09)}) .. controls (3.5, 0.5) and (3.5, 1.5) .. (5, 1.5)
            -- (\trainlength, 1.5)
            -- (\trainlength, {windshieldupy(0.09)})
            -- cycle;
    
        \foreach \x in {5,6.5,...,\trainlength} {
            \node[trainwindow] at (\x, {(windshieldupy(0.09) + 1.5)/2}) {};
        }
    
        \fill[%
            bottomtrain
        ] {%
            [rounded corners = 0.5cm]
            (\trainlength, 0.1) 
                -- (\trainlength, -1)
                -- (-0.3, -1)
                -- (-0.3, 0.1)}
            -- cycle;
            
        \begin{scope}
        
            \path[clip] {%
                [rounded corners = 0.5cm]
                (\trainlength, 0.1) 
                -- (\trainlength, -1)
                -- (-0.3, -1)
                -- (-0.3, 0.1)}
            -- cycle;
            
            \fill[trainline] (-0.3, -0.2) rectangle (\trainlength, 0.1);
            
        \end{scope}
    
        \foreach \x in {3, 11.5, 20} {
    
            \fill[
                aroundwindow
            ] (\x, -1) .. controls (\x, -0.9) and (\x, -0.9) .. ({\x + 0.1}, -0.7)
                -- ({\x + 2.9}, -0.7) .. controls ({\x + 3}, -0.9) and ({\x + 3}, -0.9) .. ({\x + 3}, -1)
                -- cycle;
        
            \begin{scope}
            
                \path[clip] (\x, -1) .. controls (\x, -0.9) and (\x, -0.9) .. ({\x + 0.1}, -0.7)
                    -- ({\x + 2.9}, -0.7) .. controls ({\x + 3}, -0.9) and ({\x + 3}, -0.9) .. ({\x + 3}, -1)
                    -- cycle;
                
                \fill[trainline] (\x, -0.8) rectangle ({\x + 3}, -0.7);
            
            \end{scope}
            
            \fill[%
                trainbody
            ] ({\x + 0.25}, -0.8) arc (-180:0:0.5); 
        
            \fill[%
                trainbody
            ] ({\x + 1.75}, -0.8) arc (-180:0:0.5); 
    
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

For the wagon, something similar can be used, albeit simpler since there is no windshield:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \definecolor{window}{RGB}{5,173,190}
        \definecolor{trainbody}{RGB}{64,75,125}
        \definecolor{aroundwindow}{RGB}{50,59,97}
        \definecolor{bottomtrain}{RGB}{27,158,249}
        \definecolor{trainline}{RGB}{164,214,249}
        
        \tikzset{%
            trainwindow/.style = {%
                rectangle,
                fill           = window,
                draw           = none,
                minimum width  = 1cm,
                minimum height = 0.5cm
            }
        }
            
        \newcommand{\trainlength}{25.5}

        \fill[trainbody] {%
            [rounded corners = 0.5cm]
                (1.5, 0) |- ({\trainlength - 1.5}, 2)
            } 
            -- ({\trainlength - 1.5}, 0)
            -- cycle;
    
        \fill[aroundwindow] (1.5, {windshieldupy(0.09)}) rectangle ({\trainlength - 1.5}, 1.5);
        
        \foreach \x in {3,4.5,...,23.5} {
            \node[trainwindow] at (\x, {(windshieldupy(0.09) + 1.5)/2}) {};
        }
    
        \fill[bottomtrain] (1.5, 0.1)
            -- ({\trainlength - 1.5}, 0.1) {%
            [rounded corners = 0.5cm]
                -- ({\trainlength - 1.5}, -1)
                -- (1.5, -1)
            } -- cycle;
    
        \fill[trainline] (1.5, -0.2) rectangle ({\trainlength - 1.5}, 0.1);

        \foreach \x in {4, 18.5} {
    
            \fill[
                aroundwindow
            ] (\x, -1) .. controls (\x, -0.9) and (\x, -0.9) .. ({\x + 0.1}, -0.7)
                -- ({\x + 2.9}, -0.7) .. controls ({\x + 3}, -0.9) and ({\x + 3}, -0.9) .. ({\x + 3}, -1)
                -- cycle;
            
            \begin{scope}
            
                \path[clip] (\x, -1) .. controls (\x, -0.9) and (\x, -0.9) .. ({\x + 0.1}, -0.7)
                    -- ({\x + 2.9}, -0.7) .. controls ({\x + 3}, -0.9) and ({\x + 3}, -0.9) .. ({\x + 3}, -1)
                    -- cycle;
                
                \fill[trainline] (\x, -0.8) rectangle ({\x + 3}, -0.7);
                
            \end{scope}
                
            \fill[%
                trainbody
            ] ({\x + 0.25}, -0.8) arc (-180:0:0.5); 
            
            \fill[%
                trainbody
            ] ({\x + 1.75}, -0.8) arc (-180:0:0.5); 
            
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: Wowwwwwww.....Surely it is a best answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano You're right, KersouMan's answer is amazing (+1!) but yours was good too. I think that you should undelete it!

Comment: @Andrew Hiii,  but it is false that my answer is good. With lot of sincerity I have put my answer because I not thinked that nobody get an answer. And in addendum the trains are perfecs and not my vagon!!! 

Comment: @Sebastiano It's a good training exercise for others, so I have voted to undelete it! :)

Comment: @Andrew No, ..fortunately there are no victims, but the train has been derailed hahahah .